# MySQL C API: variable parameters number in prepared statements

Tags: mysql, c, database, prepared-statement

I'm using the C API library and i'm implementing all my queries as prepared statements. I would like to know if it's possible for a prepared statement to have some parameters "not used". I have this query:

```
SELECT id FROM events WHERE name LIKE ? AND place LIKE ? AND lat < ? AND lng < ?
```

I don't always use all search criteria, sometimes i want search only by name, sometimes only by name and place, sometimes only by lat and name etc.
How can i do this with a single statement?

Comment: What would be wrong with having separate prepared statements and letting the logic in your C code choose which one to use?

Comment: I should prepare a statement for every possible combination? The real query is longer that this one

Comment: How many combinations are you going to have?

Comment: SELECT id FROM events WHERE name LIKE ? AND place LIKE ? AND lat < ? AND lng < ? AND fromDate > ? AND toDate > ? AND fromPrice > ? AND toPrice < ?
and who knows in the future

Comment: What keeps you from dynamically building the statement string depending on the needs during run-time? Recommend reading: [How to concatenate strings in C?](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+concatenate+strings+in+C%3F)

Comment: Nothing, just the fact that i'm trying to implement everything with prepared statements. If i wanted to dynamically build the string at runtime i'd use a normal query

Comment: A prepared statement would be prepared at run-time as well only.

Comment: Ok, so what's the reason behind "*trying to implement everything with prepared statements.*"?

Comment: And should i re-prepare it every time?